# How to detect AutoCompleteTextView popup direction

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, android-popupwindow

I'm trying to set a custom drawable to my `AutoCompleteTextView`'s popup background.

This is my drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="16dp" />

</shape>
```

As you see it has circle corners at the bottom of it. Now when popup appears at the bottom of my `AutoCompleteTextView` I have no problem. But when popup appears at top of the `AutoCompleteTextView` I want to show another drawable that has circle corners at top of it.

How can I achieve that?